# Issue with deploying a google action (updating a live version)

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

can anyone help me with this?

Actions on google deployment

[image: Actions on google deployment]

I already removed this pattern and checked several times if it exists somewhere else. Not to fine.

Please help, thank you.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Check if in any of your attempts, you have correctly defined the names of the variables, more when working in languages, remember that all must have the same variable name when selecting an entity.

For example, I once had the same error because one of the variables was different from the other variables because it was not spelled correctly.

[image: differents names variable]

It is also the case that if instead of adding a training phrase, you add an entity directly, a common mistake is that this entity has no variable assigned to it.

[image: ways to use a entity]

It doesn't necessarily have to be the same name as the entity, but it does have to be in common with the phrases you're training or variables you're already using, otherwise dialogflow will throw you the error that that entity is not linked to any variable or query.